# How to enable kmer plot for fastQC up from v. 0.11.6

Tags: bioinformatics, fastq, sequencing

I am running [fastQC](https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastqc/) on a Linux machine from the command line.

Until v.0.11.5, I was used to also get a kmer plot as an output.

Now, since v.0.11.6, Kmer output is disabled by default (see release notes) and I fail to find a way to enable it again.

I have tried running the program e.g. with the --kmers=7 option but neither in the .zip output, nor in the plot there is a kmer estimation.

Is it totally deprecated or did I miss something in the manual?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried with a newer version and no clear parameter was found. I tried with the `--kmers` parameter, but it didn't make difference. Why don't you ask the authors?

Comment: Thanks for replicating, so it seems not to be a user-error by me.
Wanted to verify this first before I contact the authors.
Will post here once I get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://github.com/s-andrews/FastQC/releases

> RELEASE NOTES FOR FastQC v0.11.6
>
> This update fixes some bugs and updates some of the functionality to
> accommodate changes in some of the sequencing platforms.
>
> There is one major change which is that by default we now disable the
> kmer module. With the inclusion of the adapter plot the value of the
> information in the Kmer plot is often not great, and it is easy to
> confound it if there are any over-represented sequences, or primer
> compositional bias. Overall therefore we consider it best to not
> routinely include this module.
>
> If you want to turn this module back on, then simply edit the
> limits.txt file in the Configuration folder of the FastQC installation
> and change the line near the top which says:
>
> kmer ignore 1
>
> ..to..
>
> kmer ignore 0
>
> ..and the module will be re-enabled.